# Subset data from original data frame using filters defined in lists

Tags: r

I have original data set  of size (1100000*62) and i need to divide data based on manual filters.

I have created a function which can separate data by   manually entering the parameters: It takes below parameters.

```
segment_dat <- function(data, Region, gtv_class_bracket, hotelclass){...}
```

Requirement :Subset of data should be  on below parameters :

1. data[[1]] should be based on NORTH-GTV1-0.5
2. data[[2]] should be based on NORTH-GTV1-5

...

120. data[[120]] should be based on SOUTH-GTV5-5

I am bit new to iterative loops. 
I have found multiple threads and i  am able to write below code , but it is not helpful as of now.final aim is to supply every data set to the another function written to do cluster analysis. Please help , if you have any leads.  Basically i need to iterate over three lists reg,gtv,hc .Final count of data sets 
should be 120 .

```
#####################################################################
############     adding segment_dat    code#########################


segment_dat<-function(data,Region,gtv_class_bracket,hotelclass) {

  ##############################if no parameters  are missing #############################
  if ( !missing(Region) & !missing(gtv_class_bracket) &!missing(hotelclass)){
    data1<-data[data$region==Region & data$gtv_class_bracket==gtv_class_bracket &
                  data$hotelclass==hotelclass,]
  }
  #################################################################################################
  ################### if two of the parameters are missing #######################################
  else if(missing(gtv_class_bracket) & missing(hotelclass) & !missing(Region)) {
    data1<-data[data$region==Region,]

  }

  else if (missing(Region) & missing(hotelclass) & !missing(gtv_class_bracket)){
    data1<-data[data$gtv_class_bracket==gtv_class_bracket,]
  }

  else if (missing(Region) & missing(gtv_class_bracket) & !missing(hotelclass))
  {
    data1<-data[data$hotelclass==hotelclass,]
  }

  ###########################################################################################  
  ######################## If any one of the parameter is missing ###########################
  else if (missing(gtv_class_bracket)){
    data1<-data[data$hotelclass==hotelclass & data$region==Region,]

  }
  else if (missing(hotelclass)){
    data1<-data[data$gtv_class_bracket==gtv_class_bracket & data$region==Region,]
  }
  else if (missing(Region)){
    data1<-data[data$gtv_class_bracket==gtv_class_bracket & data$hotelclass==hotelclass,]

  }
}
```

#

```
# example data
data=list()
reg<-as.list(c("NORTH","EAST","WEST","SOUTH"))
gtv<-as.list(c("GTV1","GTV2","GTV3","GTV4","GTV5"))
hc<-as.list(c(0.5,1,2,3,4,5))
#xx<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(reg)){
  for(j in 1:length(gtv)){
    j=i
    for(k in 1:length(hc)){
      k=j
        data[[i]]<-segment_dat(hotel_clus3,Region=reg[[i]],
                   gtv_class_bracket=gtv[[j]],hotelclass=hc[[k]])   
    }} }
```

Comment: Is "NORTH" under a specific column? Is "GTV1" under a specific column? Is "0.5" etc?

Comment: You will want to change data[[i]] to something like data[[paste(j,i,k,sep=" ")]]. Otherwise, data[[i]] will continually be written over until the last j=5 and k=6.

Comment: Can you include the contents of the `segment_dat()` function in your question?

Comment: Did you have a look at `split`? Also consider adding a derived column defined as `apply(segment_data[,c("Region", "gtv_class_bracket","hotelclass")],1,paste,sep="_")` (concatenation of the three columns)

Comment: @ChiPak  yes , NORTH,GTV1,0.5  are under specific columns.

Comment: @EricLecoutre  thanks  Eric . I will add it .

Comment: @dvantwisk  I have edited and included the  contents of segment_dat(). It is poorly written , will improve it , but it does the job .

Comment: @vrana95 The triple for-loop is very inefficient.  A better way is to think of a more vectorized approach to the `segment_dat()` function and invoke it on the `hotel_clus3`, `reg`, `gtv`, and `hc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a replacement for your `segment_dat()` function.  No triple for-loop is required to invoke it.  Below the function, it is invoked on your data.

```
segment_dat <- function(data, region, gtv_class_bracket, hotelclass){
    ## Build inputs list while checking for missing inputs
    inputs <- list()
    if(!missing(region)) inputs <- list(region=region)
    if(!missing(gtv_class_bracket) inputs <- c(inputs, list(gtv_class_bracket=gtv_class_bracket))
    if(!missing(hotelclass)) inputs <- c(inputs, hotelclass=hotelclass)
    if(inputs == 0) stop("Some subsetable column is required as input.")

    ## Build permutation data.frame
    inputs['stringsAsFactors'] <- FALSE
    values <- do.call(expand.grid, inputs)

    ## Generate list of data.frames
    apply(vals, 1, function(x) merge(data, x))
}

data <- segment_dat(hotel_clus3, reg, gtv, hc)
```

## Edit

Replaced a variable that was not present in your code; should all work now.